# Flag setting for CF , PF , AF , ZF , SF in MOV AX , BX

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

MOV AX , BX. What will be the flag settings.
So , what is the answer to this.

Comment: Intel's Software Developer's Manual includes information for every instruction about which flags it affects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No flags will get modified by the MOV instruction.